# Index out of range, but why?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview, and I have a `SelectedIndexChanged` event on it...

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow Row = GridView1.SelectedRow;

    //do some stuff
}
```

Then I get an error...

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index

I do not understand why, the Gridview is being binded in pageload. but not in post back...

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = UserAccounts;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the error is thrown on that line?

Comment: Have you forgotten to add something? Where do you get the `IndexOutOfRangeException`?

Comment: Are you doing some *stuff* at `//do some stuff` ? and you haven't mentioned where the error is thrown..

Comment: Using `SelectedRow`, is the same as retrieving the `GridViewRow` object at the index specified by the `SelectedIndex` property from the `Rows` collection (`GridView1.Rows[GridView1.SelectedIndex]`). If no row is selected the `SelectedIndex` is -1, which would throw an exception. So, have you debugged to see that there are items and that the index is more than -1?

Comment: With regards to "I dont understand why, the Gridview is being binded in pageload. but not in post back...", you are binding it within a conditional statement that fails on PostBack. Remove the `if {}` block.

Comment: Microsoft says that `SelectedRow` is the same as `GridView1.Rows[GridView1.SelectedIndex]` but this isn't exactly true. Using a decompiler and looking at `SelectedRow` and `SelectedIndex` indicates that if SelectedRow is -1 then the returned object is `null`. `SelectedRow` will **never** throw an exception and neither will `SelectedIndex` (unless you set `SelectedIndex` to a value < -1 and in that case it will throw `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`). The exception must be happening on a different line.

Comment: Sorry, the error is thrown on "GridViewRow Row = GridView1.SelectedRow;"

I read that i should bind on !IsPostBack only, which worked. But then it just started failing again. really strange! 

I am doing some stuff at //do some stuff. i just didn't want to post the rest of the code because its' failing at the line above.

Answer (score 3):

The asp.net `DataSource` controls handle this for you automatically but if you are manually binding your `GridView`, you will need to also bind it on `PostBack`. If you make changes to the data source based on filters, etc., you will need to rebind it.

Comment: I have tried binding on postpage as well, and i still get the error :(

Answer (score 1):

The first thing: When post back to server, your GridView1 will re-initialize so that GridView1.DataSource will lost the previous data

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
        GridView1.DataSource = UserAccounts;
        GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

The second thing: if you manually bind your GridView with your custom DataTable, List .... you must implement RowCommand with specific DataKey.

Please take a look at this article http://aspspirits.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-get-rowindex-of-aspnet-gridview.html

Comment: Checking the post back, Helped.